# Is there an equivalent of isitruby19 for rubinius?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubinius

Is there a web site that indicates which gems work on rubinius (or other implementations of ruby), like isitruby19.com indicates which gems work on ruby 1.9? (I'm curious about heckle working with rubinius in particular)

Comment: There's now a site for JRuby: http://isitjruby.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, see here: http://isitrubinius.com/

Answer (score 1):

There isn't as far as I know. If you want to know whether something works, you can download it and run its unit tests. Heckle won't work out of the box because it requires ParseTree, which merely raises a LoadError that says "ParseTree isn't needed with Rubinius."

Comment: Thanks. My head exploded after the last sentence, though.

Comment: I know. If you don't have ParseTree, it complains that you need it. If you do have ParseTree, it complains that you don't need it. The only winning move is not to play.

Comment: It is not needed, as Rubinius can give you s-expressions for ruby code out of the box and ParseTree only works for MRI.